# Find a record in json Object if the record has specific key in python

Tags: json, python-3.x, jq

I have a JSON object which has 100000 records. I want a select a record which has specific value to the one of the key

Eg:

```
[{
    "name": "bindu",
    "age": "24",
    "qualification": "b.tech" 
},
{
    "name": "naveen",
    "age": "23",
    "qualification": "b.tech"
},
{
    "name": "parvathi",
    "age": "23",
    "qualification": "m.tech"
},
{
    "name": "bindu s",
    "status": "married"
},
{
    "name": "naveen k",
    "status": "unmarried"

}]
```

now I want to combine the records which are having the name with 'bindu' and 'bindu s. We can achieve this by iterating on the JSON object but since the size is more it is taking more time. Is there any way to make this easy.

I want the output like

```
[{
    "name": "bindu",
    "age": "24",
    "qualification": "b.tech",
    "status": "married"
},
{
    "name": "naveen",
    "age": "23",
    "qualification": "b.tech",
    "status": "unmarried"

},
{
    "name": "parvathi",
    "age": "23",
    "qualification": "m.tech"
    "status": ""
},
```

Comment: What you posted is not valid JSON.

Comment: I added the sample JSON file to explain my question.

Comment: You should store the records in a database such as sqlite3 instead with `name` as an index if you want to be able to quickly retrieve a record by key.

Comment: If you have code you wish help improving, you should post it on CodeReview.

Comment: what is your current approach? how much time it takes?  is your concern that the search time outweighs the JSON growth (e.g.:. the latter grows linearly, while the former grows exponentially)? or it's a different one?

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines.  Also, the question as asked is very unclear.  Perhaps it would be clearer if you showed the code that is functionally correct. What output are you expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will rename and merge your objects by first name.

```
jq 'map(.name |= split(" ")[0]) | group_by(.name) | map(add)'
```